# How can I display sprites in random places every launching of game in Unity[c#]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making bubble shooter replica in unity and I encountered a problem with initalizing the bubbles in random places, should I create an array of them in the background class?
For example i have class Sprite1 and Sprite2 and I want to display them in random places in the background how can I do it?
This is how it looks.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/axGBu.jpg
And below it's my attempt to display it by for loop, but dont know the method.

```
void Start () {
    Random.Range(0f,4.5f);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Sprite.Create(?)

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post what you've already try (scripting, results, what didn't work properly, ...) so people can try to adapt to your situation. There're many ways of doing it.

Comment: Check out [ask], [mcve], and [help/on-topic]

Comment: @Kardux actually I really have no idea what to do now, I've tried to do for loop in background class to, which would loop 100 times and each time create a sprite in random place.

Comment: void Start () {
        Random.Range(0f,4.5f);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Sprite.Create(?)

        }
  
 }

Comment: @KrzysztofMaliszewski Please edit your question to integrate your code (not readable in comments): use links provided by Tim to provide a code that can easily be debugged :)

Comment: @Kardux edited :)

Comment: To start with `Random.Range(0f,4.5f);` will do nothing the way you are using it. It will return a float that you would need to capture in a variable. At the moment, the result just disappears.

Comment: Well to me it seems like you didn't tried anything so far... I feels like you placed the current bubble one by one on your scene but have absolutely no script to achieve this: Stack Overflow isn't a scripting service, you have to come with something that you've tried/done and only after researching on your own once you need help with it. I'll try to explain you a bit how your game is supposed to work but later (busy right now).

Comment: Also look into this documentation for help on the other issue. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: Random.Range() was to generate random Y coordinate but I didnt know anyway how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying your bubbles *randomly* in the background all depends on what your "randomly" word means: if it like randomly on a grid, completely randomly, can they overlay other bubbles, ...

So here's a first approach to your problem using a grid generation: to generate your bubbles, you can either use the [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) method or create new [GameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html)s.

Your game seems to be a 2D one so I highly recommend you looking for the [Unity UI tutorials](https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui). Once you'll understand the basics of the UI system, create a **Canvas** and add an empty game object to it. Afterward you can assign it the below script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
public class TestScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float m_BubbleSize;

    [SerializeField]
    private int m_BubbleColumns;
    [SerializeField]
    private int m_BubbleRows;

    [SerializeField]
    private Sprite[] m_BubbleSprites;

    private GameObject[][] m_Bubbles;

    void Start()
    {
        GenerateBubbles();
    }

    private void GenerateBubbles()
    {
        // Position of the most top left bubble
        Vector3 initialPosition = GetComponent<RectTransform>().position;
        initialPosition.y += GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height * 0.5f;
        initialPosition.y -= 0.5f * m_BubbleSize;
        initialPosition.x -= (m_BubbleColumns - 1) * 0.5f * m_BubbleSize;
        initialPosition.x -= 0.25f * m_BubbleSize;

        // Rows height: comes from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres
        float rowsHeight = Mathf.Sqrt(6.0f * m_BubbleSize * m_BubbleSize) / 3.0f;

        // Bubbles references array
        m_Bubbles = new GameObject[m_BubbleColumns][];
        for(int i = 0; i < m_Bubbles.Length; i++)
        {
            m_Bubbles[i] = new GameObject[m_BubbleRows];
        }

        // Generation
        for(int x = 0; x < m_Bubbles.Length; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < m_Bubbles[x].Length; y++)
            {
                GameObject bubble = new GameObject("Bubble_" + x.ToString() + y.ToString(), new System.Type[] { typeof(RectTransform), typeof(Image), typeof(CircleCollider2D) });
                bubble.transform.SetParent(transform);

                if(y % 2 == 0)
                {
                    bubble.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = initialPosition + new Vector3(x * m_BubbleSize, -y * rowsHeight, 0.0f);
                }
                else
                {
                    bubble.GetComponent<RectTransform>().position = initialPosition + new Vector3(0.5f * m_BubbleSize + x * m_BubbleSize, -y * rowsHeight, 0.0f);
                }
                bubble.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = new Vector2(m_BubbleSize, m_BubbleSize);

                bubble.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = m_BubbleSprites[Random.Range(0, m_BubbleSprites.Length)];

                bubble.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>().radius = m_BubbleSize * 0.5f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To complete your game here are the few (maybe not exhaustive list) steps you will need to go through:

- Populating a list of the potential "cell" where bubbles can be
- Creating a pool of bubble to be fired (with random shuffling)
- Writing the shooting + rebounds dynamic (Unity 2D Physic can help with that)
- Detecting collision after bubble has been fired
- Finding nearest possible "cell"
- Searching if enough bubbles are connected (and if so destroying them)
- Searching if some of the bubbles aren't connected anymore (and if so deleting them too)
- *OPTIONAL* Implementing a scoring system (and saving the scores)
- *OPTIONAL* Implementing apparition of new bubbles row on top every X bubbles fired
- ...

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: Thank you a lot! <3